# I am new to .batch file and I am trying to Develop a time converter

Tags: batch-file

So I have come up with this one. What do I have to change?

```
@echo off 
:U 
echo ****************** Time Converter!  ****************** 
set /p HOUR= Please Enter the Hours: 
set /p MIN= Plese Enter the Minutes:

if %hr% geq 12 (Set timeofday=pm) else (Set timeofday=am) 
if %hr% equ 0 (set /a HOUR=%HOUR%+12) 
if %hr% gtr 0 (set /a HOUR=%HOUR%) 
if %hr% gtr 12 (set /a HOUR=%HOUR%-12)

echo The time in 12hours is %HOUR%:%MIN%%timeofday%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a courtesy, here's a more robustly coded example of your task, to cater for the many issues your code could have caused. I will leave it for you to review, research, and try to learn from.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Echo ****************** Time Converter ******************

:GetHours
Set "_Hour="
Set /P "_Hour=Please enter the hour>" || GoTo GetHours
Set _Hour | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RXC:"_Hour=[0123456789]"^
 /C:"_Hour=1[0123456789]" /C:"_Hour=2[01234]" 1>NUL || GoTo GetHours
Set "AMPM=AM" & If %_Hour% GEq 12 If %_Hour% LEq 23 Set "AMPM=PM"
If %_Hour% NEq 12 Set /A _Hour %%= 12

:GetMins
Set "_Min="
Set /P "_Min=Enter the number of minutes past the hour>" || GoTo GetMins
Set _Min | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RXC:"_Min=[0123456789]"^
 /C:"_Min=[12345][0123456789]" 1>NUL || GoTo GetMins
If %_Min% LEq 9 Set "_Min=0%_Min%"

Echo The 12 hour clock time is %_Hour%:%_Min%%AMPM%
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1>NUL
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This has helped me greatly, I will learn many from this thanks!

Comment: @Compo I decided to post in an answer my extended version of __your__ script. Thanks for the main code making it easy to extend the time converter.

Comment: That's fine, and probably makes more sense, should others find that your interpretation was closer to their own than mine @Mofi

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended version of the batch file written by [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72940522/3074564).

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Echo ****************** Time Converter ******************

:GetHour
Set "_Hour="
Set /P "_Hour=Please enter the hour> " || GoTo GetHour
Set _Hour | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RXC:"_Hour=[0123456789]" /C:"_Hour=[01][0123456789]" /C:"_Hour=2[0123]" 1>NUL || GoTo GetHour
if %_Hour:~0,1% == 0 if not "%_Hour:~1%" == "" set _Hour=%_Hour:~1%
Set "AMPM=AM" & If %_Hour% GEq 12 If %_Hour% LEq 23 Set "AMPM=PM"
If %_Hour% NEq 12 Set /A _Hour %%= 12
If %_Hour% LEq 9 Set "_Hour=0%_Hour%"

:GetMin
Set "_Min="
Set /P "_Min=Please enter the minute> " || GoTo GetMin
Set _Min | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RXC:"_Min=[0123456789]" /C:"_Min=[012345][0123456789]" 1>NUL || GoTo GetMin
if %_Min:~0,1% == 0 if not "%_Min:~1%" == "" set _Min=%_Min:~1%
If %_Min% LEq 9 Set "_Min=0%_Min%"

Echo The 12 hour clock time is: %_Hour%:%_Min% %AMPM%
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1>NUL
EndLocal
```

It has following extensions:

1. It does not accept `24` for the hour.
2. It accepts a two digit value for hour and minute with a leading `0`.
3. It outputs the time always with two digits for the hour and the minute and with a space between minute and `AM` or `PM`.

Comment: Thank you! I have learned a lot from your code!